# How can I hide a specific app in the Notification area?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

I want to only hide *Privoxy* (it's a web proxy) present in the Notification area. Is it possible using REG file or through the Local Group Policy Editor?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Choose *Hide icon and notifications* from that combo box.

Comment: No, that's not it.......I want to completely wipe it off from the system tray. I don't want other user to see.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to run the application as a different user.

1. Open a command prompt.
2. In the command prompt, type the command below, and press Enter

NOTE: You would substitute USER-NAME in the command with the actual name of the user account that you want to run the program as. If the user account is on a domain, then you would use UserName@Domain or Domain\UserName for the user name instead.

```
 runas /user:USER-NAME "C:\full\path\of\Program.exe"
```

For example, if I wanted to run Notepad as the test user, I would type this command below.

```
runas /user:test "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

3. Type in the password of the user account that you want to run this program as. (see screenshot above)
4. If prompted by UAC, then click/tap on Yes.
5. The program will now be running as that user.
6. When done, simply close the program to stop it from running as that user.

To Create a RunAs Shortcut for the Program
Run as Different User Shortcut - Create for Specified Program and User
OR
Open Notepad.
Type the command from step 2 above in Notepad.
Click on File (menu bar) and Save as in Notepad.
Navigate to your desktop.
Type in name-you-want.bat, and click on the Save button.
You will now be able to just run this shortcut or .bat file to have the program runas the user you want.

Comment: Do I have to create a new user account? If so,I would prefer a different method, any advice?

Comment: You can use any account besides the one which owns the current desktop instance.

Comment: Let me be more clear, My sister and I share the computer,so if she sees the new account, I will be in trouble. (please don't ask me why?,it's a long story). Any other solutions?